# Scraping carousell with puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am currently doing a project that needs to scrape a data from the search result in carousell.ph

I basically made a sample HTML and replicate the output HTML of carousell, so far the javascript work except when I tried to migrate it using puppeteer it always gives me an error.

The task is basically get all the product list from the search url "https://www.carousell.ph/search/iphone"

Here's the code I made.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    let url = 'https://www.carousell.ph/search/iphone';
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 10000});
    await page.setViewport({ width: 2195, height: 1093 });
    await page.screenshot({ fullPage: true, path: 'carousell.png' });
    document.querySelectorAll('main').forEach(main => {
        main.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(product => {
            const product_details = product.querySelectorAll('p');
            const productName = product.textContent;
            const productHref = product.getAttribute('href');
            console.log(product_details[0].textContent + " - "+ product_details[1].textContent);
        });
    });

    await browser.close()

})()
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: node:8980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: document is not defined (node:8980) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8980) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a 
non-zero exit code.

Comment: You should use the `evaluate` function if you want to execute code inside the browser. That's why document is not defined because you are on the node side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @hardkoded stated, document is not something that is out of the box in puppeteer, it's  dogma in the browser, but not in Node.js. You also do not need to for each in Node.js. The Map Technique outlined in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pixfH6yyqZk) is very helpful and quick. I'd make sure also to keep await on your loop or map technique, because the function is asynchronous so you want to make sure the promise comes back resolved.

**Map technique**

An extremely fast way to get many elements into an array from a page is to use a function like below. So instead of getting an array of the elements and then looping them for their properties. You can create a function like this below using $$eval and map. The result is a formatted JSON array that takes all the looping out of the equation.

```
const links = await first_state_list.$$eval("li.stateList__item", links =>
      links.map(ele2 => ({
        State_nme: ele2.querySelector("a").innerText.trim(), //GET INNER TEXT
        State_url: ele2.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href") //get the HREF
      }))
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Already made it work.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    let searchItem = 'k20&20pro';
    let carousellURL = 'https://www.carousell.ph/search/' + searchItem;
    await page.goto(carousellURL, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 100000});
    //await page.goto(carousellURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    await page.setViewport({ 
        width: 2195, 
        height: 1093 
    });
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
    })
    await timeout(15000);
    await page.screenshot({ 
        fullPage: true, 
        path: 'carousell.png' 
    });

    var data = await page.evaluate(() =>
        Array.from(
            document.querySelectorAll('main div a:nth-child(2)')).map(products => products.href
        )
    )

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        console.log(data[i]);
        // comment this section but this will open the page to get product details.
        //await page.goto(data[1], {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});

        // inner product page details
        // this will get the title
        // document.querySelectorAll('h1')[0].innerText;
        // this will get the amount
        // document.querySelectorAll('h2')[0].innerText;
        // this will get the description
        // document.querySelectorAll('section div div:nth-child(4) p')[0].innerText;
        // this will get sellers name
        // document.querySelectorAll('div div:nth-child(2) a p')[0].innerText;

        let ss_filename = 'carousellph_'+searchItem+'_'+i+'.png';
        console.log(ss_filename);
        console.log("\r\n");
        //await page.screenshot({ fullPage: false, path: ss_filename });
    }

    await browser.close()

})()
```

Comment: Great since you went with the map array from technique, can you accept answer :)?